# Is there a way to do full text search in uspto image file wrapper?

Tags: uspto

At the moment I'm manually entering the application number and reading the contents of image file wrapper in USPTO public pair.

Is there a website where all USPTO application's image file wrapper content is indexed. So I can perform a full text search?

I'm more interested in office actions and applicant arguments.

Thanks